# How to optimize the search SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, optimization, query-optimization

I have written a search query which searches for similar names. It works with **Power Set** of  tags and it sorts by **similarity**. for example if the search text is: `shakespeare tragedy hamlet`

the SQL generated is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM books 
      WHERE name LIKE '%shakespeare%' 
      AND name LIKE '%tragedy%' 
      AND name LIKE '%hamlet%' limit 10)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM books 
      WHERE name LIKE '%shakespeare%' 
      AND name LIKE '%tragedy%' limit 10)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM books 
      WHERE name LIKE '%shakespeare%'  
      AND name LIKE '%hamlet%' limit 10)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM books 
      WHERE name LIKE '%tragedy%' 
      AND name LIKE '%hamlet%' limit 10)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM books WHERE name LIKE '%shakespeare%' limit 10)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM books WHERE name LIKE '%tragedy%' limit 10)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM books WHERE name LIKE '%hamlet%' limit 10)
) limit 10
```

there are two problems:

1. The Power Set creates `2^tags - 1` unions in my query, which means if some one wants to be precise and uses 6 tags, it will be 63 unions and it makes my query much slower.
2. if the first union returns 10 rows, others are useless.

Is there a way to optimize this query?

Comment: Where is the code that generates this sql? And are you looking only for a row that will contain all tags? or 1 of them is enough like the last 3 rows of your query

Comment: @sagi I believe everyone knows how the powerset works, that is why I didn't go through generation code. I am looking for similar rows sorted by similarities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get all boosk where name is similar to past tag and add a custom ORDER BY based on similarity. If name contains tag +1 if not 0. SO if name contains all the 3 tags sum is 3 if just one sum is 1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM books 
where name LIKE '%shakespeare%'
   OR name LIKE '%tragedy%'
   OR name LIKE '%hamlet%'
ORDER BY IF(INSTR(name, 'shakespeare')>0,1,0)+
         IF(INSTR(name, 'tragedy')>0,1,0)+
         IF(INSTR(name, 'hamlet')>0,1,0) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

UPDATE: ORDER BY could be based on sum or just commas

Comment: Yes, descending. Sorry forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to `FULLTEXT` index and use

```
MATCH(name) AGAINST('shakespeare tragedy hamlet')
```

you can get a somewhat reasonable ordering, and run a *lot* faster.

If you want to insist on `shakespeare` being in the string, but the others are optional, this works better: `'+shakespeare tragedy hamlet'`.

Caveat:  There are both benefits and limitations of `FULLTEXT`.